# Typescript: Optional function arguments cause problems in function body

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, optional-arguments

I am new to TypeScript and have a little problem with an optional argument in a function. I got the following error in Visual Studio Code for the `query` argument (see screen shot). I really don't understand this error, because I defined the type as `string`. So why do I get this error?

> message: 'Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'

[image: Screen shot error in VS Code]

```
public async fetchPut<T>(requestURL: string, body: TBody, query?: string): Promise<T> {

    const finalRequestOption: IFetchOption = Object.assign({
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: this.headers
    }, { body });

    const response: Response = await this.httpClient.fetch(
            this.getRequestURL(requestURL, query), 
            finalRequestOption);

    return response.json();
}
```

Comment: Which line produces that error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getRequestURL` function expects `query` to be a `string`, but `fetchPut` function defines query as `string | undefined` (optional parameter).

You can define `query` parameter of `getRequestURL` as optional as well:

```
getRequestURL(requestURL: string, query?: string)
```

Or provide default value for it:

```
getRequestURL(requestURL: string, query: string = '')
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Why do you get this error?

First, the type of `query` is not `string` but is the union type of `string | undefined`. That is because [optional parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html) have a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) of `T | undefined`.

Second, assigning a variable of type `T | undefined` to a variable of type `T` does not compile when TypeScript 2.0 uses strict null checks. [From the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html):

> ...whereas `T` and `T | undefined` are considered synonymous in regular type checking mode (because undefined is considered a subtype of any T), they are different types in strict type checking mode...

[image: VS Code with strict null checks does report the problem.]

#### How do you fix this error?

One option is to set `strictNullChecks` to `false` in your tsconfig.json file.

[image: VS Code without strict null checks does not report the problem.]

Comment: You wrote that one option is to set strictNullChecks to false. I wonder if there are other options? I find it surprising that the TS compiler would keep emitting this error even for a parameter that is marked as optional and that the only solution is to disable a check that would otherwise be useful.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that Typescript wants you to put a type check before the function call, to eliminate "undefined" from the list of possible types. Eg:

```
if (typeof myVar !== 'undefined') {
    myFunction(myVar);
}
```

Or, because 'undefined' is falsy, you could use the double-bang boolean-casting trick:

```
if (!!myVar) { myFunction(myVar); }
```